# Unable to ping local IP address back from Alibaba ECS

Tags: alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

I have an ECS instance running in alibaba. My ECS is in a VPC that has a SSL server. I have downloaded the SSL client certificate which allows me to connect to openVPN and to ping the ECS instance from my local box while connected to openVPN.

However, when I login to the ECS instance, I am unable to ping back my local box. My security group is a basic one which allows all connections. I didn't touch the outbound connection.

[image]

[image]

Here are the details of my SSL Server, and successful ping screenshot (My ECS Primary Private IP Address is 192.168.0.201)

[image]

[image]

Here is a screenshot of my unsuccessful attempt to ping my local home IP address (The IP, 192.168.10.190，in the screenshot below is an arbitrary one for illustration purpose) from the ECS instance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you connect to VPN, you're assigned a **private client IP** of `192.168.2.0/24` as per your SSL VPN settings. This is the network that will be used for your VPN connection. From your screenshot I see that you're pinging to your local `192.168.10.190`. Your cloud server does not have access to this network.

You can try pinging to your client `192.168.2.0/24` IP from your ECS. You probably will need to a the route to your `VPC > Route Tables`. I haven't tried connecting cloud server via SSL VPN myself, but I've used IPSec for two-way site-to-site connection, which is more suitable for this situation.